# Unique "resume" link

Tags: cognito-forms

I am hoping to send out an email to everybody who has not completed our organization's form through Cognito Forms. Due to the high volume of incomplete forms currently in our database, I would love to send each person their unique "resume" link in a mass email or text. I would match their email with the link.

I do not see the resume link in the JSON object anywhere. Would be massive for form submissions for all clients, I imagine, if possible!

Has anybody has been able to do this/is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hack/workaround way to do this that I discovered. Go to the Entries page. Select the checkbox by all users that you want to send email to. Click on the action menu, and change status > Incomplete. This will trigger an email to be sent to all users that will have a link to their personal form. Also if they are already marked as Incomplete, you might need to set them as reviewed first, and then change them back to Incomplete.